# Getting error "Incorrect syntax near ','"

Tags: c#, sql-server, syntax-error

I have been running into this error for a while now, and still haven't been able to solve it. I am trying to Update the data in my database, with a button press in a windows form.

I am using SQL Server 2011.

```
private void btnEdit_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MainMenu mainmenu = new MainMenu();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update PresentationSpec SET Pres_name = @Pres_name, Prestor_name = @Prestor_name, Pres_Summary = @Pres_Summary, Est_Length = @Est_Length, Date_Presented = @Date_Presented WHERE Id=" + mainmenu.tbxSelected);
    cmd.Connection=connection;
    connection.Open();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pres_name", tbxpresName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Prestor_name", tbxprstorName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pres_Summary", rtbSummary.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Est_Length", tbxLength.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date_Presented", tbxDate.Text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    this.Close();
    Form2 editscreen = new Form2();
    Refresh();
}
```

If anyone knows what's wrong, please tell me.

Comment: What are the concrete TexBoxes values?

Comment: There is no SQL Server **2011** - we have 2000, 2005, 2008, 2008 R2, 2012, 2014, 2016 and 2017 - so which one is it really??

Comment: What's *probably* wrong is the content of `mainmenu.tbxSelected`, I suggest you examine that.

Comment: And why are you using parameters for your values in the `SET` part - but not for the  `WHERE` clause?? Use a parameter there, too! That'll fix your issue

Comment: First guess: what are the sql types of the columns `Est_Length` and `Date_Presented`? You provide the parameters as `string`, but I guess the types are rather `int` and `DateTime`. So you'll need to parse `tbx.Length.Text` to an `int` and `tbxDate.Text` to a `DateTime`, otherwise `AddWithValue` will tell the SQL that these are `nvarchar` or something, which will probably cause the error.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: that looks like an error generated by sql-server - reporting that the SQL query is invalid. Possibly a blank value from a textbox.

Comment: +1 for what marc_s said. That is the only place where you could possibly get a spurious apostrophe that is currently breaking your query //// assuming no bugs in the framework ofc

Comment: Wow that is some kind of special mixing bound parameters and string concatenation

Comment: @RenéVogt, I actually used string for those, for some reason, but I guess it worked out.

Comment: @marc_s, Right after I fixed the comma error, another syntax error came up, but I used your solution and it worked! So it ended up being 2 errors instead of one. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are appending

```
mainmenu.tbxSelected
```

whereas I suspect that your intention was to append

```
mainmenu.tbxSelected.Text
```

The former would probably result in a fully qualified typename in your WHERE clause, which would contain commas.

As an aside, you should be aware that constructing SQL in this way leaves you potentially open to SQL Injection attacks. If that's a concern, you may be better off considering a stored procedure, or an ORM tool (such as Entity Framework).

Comment: Thanks, This helped!